# cannot return reference to local variable `s0`

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and I'm getting an error which I wasn't able to solve on my own.

I was advised to use a Cow but the person then said it wasn't possible after further inspection.

Link to playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d2910c05fed1ed8c615c28eaddf77d1d

Code:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

enum Value<'a> {
    Symbol(&'a str),
    Call(&'a str, Vec<&'a Value<'a>>),
}

enum V<'a> {
    Null,
    String(&'a str),
    Symbol(&'a str),
    Builtin(Box<dyn for<'b> Fn(Vec<&'b V>) -> V<'b>>),
    Function(Vec<&'a str>, &'a ()),
}

struct S<'a> {
    i: HashMap<&'a str, V<'a>>,
    parent: Option<&'a S<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> S<'a> {
    fn lookup(&self, name: &str) -> &V<'a> {
        match self.i.get(name) {
            Some(v) => v,
            None => match self.parent {
                Some(parent) => parent.lookup(name),
                None => &V::Null,
            },
        }
    }
    fn put(&mut self, name: &'a str, v: V<'a>) {
        self.i.entry(name).or_insert(v);
    }
}

fn eval<'a>(val: &'a Value, s: &'a S<'a>) -> V<'a> {
    match val {
        Value::Symbol(str) => V::Symbol(str),
        Value::Call(str, args) => match s.lookup(str) {
            V::Builtin(_fn) => {
                let args: Vec<&V> = args
                    .iter()
                    .map(|z| {
                        let s0 = eval(z, s);
                        match s0 {
                            V::Symbol(str) => s.lookup(str),
                            _ => &s0
                        }
                    })
                    .collect();

                _fn(args)
            }
            _ => V::Null,
        },
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut m = S {
        i: HashMap::new(),
        parent: None,
    };

    m.put("x", V::Null);

    m.put("y", V::Builtin(Box::new(|_x| V::Null)));

    let v = Value::Call("y", vec![&Value::Symbol("x")]);

    eval(&v, &m);
}
```

And the error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to local variable `s0`
  --> src/main.rs:47:34
   |
47 | ...                   _ => &s0
   |                            ^^^ returns a reference to data owned by the current function
```

Comment: What do you expect `&s0` to do? It's a reference to a local variable, as the error points out correctly. In other low-level languages, this would silently compile to comically incorrect code, so be glad you caught this early.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Do you have any advice as to what I could to do get around using a reference? I don't believe I can implement the Copy trait because of the Builtin enum value.

Comment: Are your builtin functions always Rust top-level functions (as opposed to closures or other objects)? If so, you can get rid of the trait object and just do `Builtin(fn(Vec<&'b V>) -> V<'b>)` (Note the lowercase 'f' in `fn`; it's a function pointer, not the `Fn` trait), which would let you `#[derive(Clone)]` on your data type.

Comment: You won't be able to get `Copy` because of the vectors either way. But if you can rid of the trait object, you may be able to get `Clone` and do an explicit `.clone()`.

Comment: I believe this has fixed the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Great! I'll summarize our discussion as an answer to this question, for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `eval` function is creating data and trying to return it. You probably want to return it by value, without the reference.

```
_ => s0
```

If you don't own the data, then you'll need to make a clone of it. Your type makes extensive use of `Vec`, so it'll never be able to implement `Copy`. It's pretty close to implementing `clone`, though. The only issue is

```
Builtin(Box<dyn for<'b> Fn(Vec<&'b V>) -> V<'b>>),
```

There's no general way to `clone` a `dyn Fn`. If you really need general cloning on something like that, you can look into reference-counted types like `Rc` and `Arc`, but that's probably massively overkill for this.

Assuming `Builtin` refers to a handful of language builtins that are set at compile-time, they're probably all top-level Rust functions. The type `Fn` encompasses not just ordinary functions but also closures (and, I believe in new versions of Rust, any user-defined class can implement that trait as well by hand). If all you need is ordinary closures, use `fn` (note the lowercase "f"). This will only allow ordinary Rust function pointers, not closures or anything more advanced.

```
Builtin(fn(Vec<&'b V>) -> V<'b>),
```

The nice thing about `fn` (as opposed to `dyn Fn`) is that it's `Clone`, so we can `#[derive(Clone)]` now.